# Getting group value of element ID with Regex/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a DIV with element id; e.g. "bgjhkn2n2-20". I'm trying to get the regex right so I can load reports dynamically into div's based on id.

console.log(elemID) prints the bgjhkn2n2-20 as expected. It's not printing the # that normally prefixes element Id. `console.log(repDBID[0])` prints the full element ID; but I can not get firebug to print the groups I get from a similar test in a regextester with `console.log(repDBID[0])`. If I append an index number to the match statement, it returns null.

Help?

```
var baseURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/db/";
var genREP = "?a=API_GenResultsTable&qid=";

$('#tab1 div').each(function (e){
    var elemID = this.getAttribute('id');
    console.log(elemID);
    var pattern=/([a-z0-9]{9})-([1-9]{1}[0-9]*)/g
    var repDBID = elemID.match(pattern); //get dbid    
    console.log(repDBID[0]);
    var repID = elemID.match(pattern)[2]; //get qid
    //console.log(repID);
    //$(this).load(baseURL+repDBID+genREP+repID);
     $('#repTabs').tab(); //initialize tabs
});
```

Comment: What is your question?  There is no `#` in an id value.  That is added only to tell a CSS selector engine that you are looking for an id value.  It is not actually present in the id value.

Comment: Well; when testing with something like http://www.regextester.com/ or rubular.com ; I get three groups for the regex pattern match. Group 0 - the entire ID (if it matches the pattern). Group 1 - the initial 9 character alphanumeric set. and Group 2 - the remaining numbers after the hyphen. How do I access those groups individually and use them to create a url (see code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `g` from your regex and it should work just fine:

```
var baseURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/db/";
var genREP = "?a=API_GenResultsTable&qid=";

$('#tab1 div').each(function(e) {  // You might need `#tab1 > div`
    var parts = this.id.match(/([a-z0-9]{9})-([1-9]{1}[0-9]*)/);
    var repDBID = parts[1];
    var repID = parts[2];

    $(this).load(baseURL + repDBID + genREP + repID);

    $('#repTabs').tab();
});
```

Here's what I mean:

```
> id.match(/([a-z0-9]{9})-([1-9]{1}[0-9]*)/g);
["bgjhkn2n2-20"]
> id.match(/([a-z0-9]{9})-([1-9]{1}[0-9]*)/);
["bgjhkn2n2-20", "bgjhkn2n2", "20"]
```

Comment: Hmm, when I run your code or a similar edited version of my code in Firebug; it works and loads the content for tab1 --- but on page load it doesn't work. Any ideas?